# Aspect : "execution time" on the every linux command executed

Tags: linux, shell

Wanted to add aspect:executionTime for each linux command performed

Is there any way to add the add the default aspect environment such that have to get the executionTime for the linux command executed

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "aspect" here. There is the `time` command. Maybe you want to take a look at that.

Comment: time we can add before and after, we can diff its the execTime, But I want it to be in default environment of linux, when it is required we have to toggle, Aspect is an analogy to the Spring-Aspect where we are able to calculate the methodExecutionTime

Comment: You may want to read about the `time` command again. Have a try reading its man page: `man time`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Prompting section of `man bash` you can use `\t` to include the current time in the prompt. For example:

```
$ PS1='\t \$ '
13:44:13 $
```

This of course does not include the time it takes to type the next command, so its utility depends on how accurate you want to be.